# php json decode how to show select items

Tags: php, json, foreach

I'm using this php code to json decode a facebook pages's albums xml file and echo each album id. Each album in the xml has the arrays of data->id.

There is one album with the id of '10150243262627075' that I don't want echoed, but I can't figure out a way to make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

```
$json = json_decode($this->curlGetFile($this->URL));
if($json -> error) die("THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR");

foreach($json->data as $v)
{
echo "Album Id: ".$v->id;
}
```

Comment: just add condition   if($v->id!==10150243262627075){//your echo }

Comment: I tried an if statement before but was using !$v->id== instead of $v->id!== , works like a charm. Thanks Yaroslav!

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is continue; :)

```
$json = json_decode($this->curlGetFile($this->URL));
if($json -> error) die("THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR");

foreach($json->data as $v)
{
     if($v->id == "10150243262627075") continue;
     echo "Album Id: ".$v->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $json = json_decode($this->curlGetFile($this->URL));
 if($json -> error) die("THERE HAS BEEN AN ERROR");

 foreach($json->data as $v) {
      if($v->id != "10150243262627075") echo "Album Id: ".$v->id;
 }
```